# What's the difference between these two addEvent functions?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, attachevent

This is the first:

```
function addEvent(el, type, fn){
    if(el.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }else{
        el[fn] = function(){
            fn.call(el, window.event);
        }
        el.attachEvent('on'+type, el[fn]);
    }
}
```

and the second:

```
function addEvent(el, type, fn){
    if(el.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }else{  
        el['e' + fn] = function(){
            fn.call(el, window.event);
        }
        el.attachEvent('on'+type, el['e'+fn]);
    }
}
```

the second one just add a prefix, what's it use for?

Comment: This is jquery source correct? Which version is it and are both functions from the same version. (Some context would help here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like both functions try to do the same thing: bind event handlers in a way that is consistent across browsers (i.e., older IE versions that don't support `.addEventListener()`). If the `.addEventListener()` method is available it is used, otherwise it creates a proxy function that ensures the callback function is called with appropriate values for `this` and the event object.

The difference is only in `el[fn]` versus `el['e' + fn]` when creating and later referencing a property on the element:

```
    el[fn] = function(){
        fn.call(el, window.event);
    }
```

The `fn` parameter of `addEvent()` must be a function reference, and offhand I'm not certain what happens if you use a function reference as a property name but I would guess that it essentially does a `toString()` on the function and uses the result as the property name. So `el['e' + fn]` would do the same thing but add `'e'` to the beginning. I don't see that the "e" has any special meaning.